# INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with different keys

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have 4 tables, one that holds all the values that need to be distributed across the other 3 depending on a value of one column.

So I would like to do INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but the problem I am facing is that I can not make the same key on the main table as on the other 3 tables.

Example key on main table (a, b, c, d) while key on child table would be (a, b, c) if I do it like this, will the query still work?

I am using mysql 5.6

I did try this on local machine, but while I did not get any errors I also did not get desired result.

My query looks like this

```
INSERT INTO table2
(a, b, c, d)
SELECT
    a, b, c, d
FROM table1 AS t
WHERE t.id <> 0
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                     a = t.a
                     b = t.b
```

Comment: So what is the desired result? And what do you get?

Comment: I don't understand the question - the on duplicate key applies only to the table being inserted to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a query of that pattern would work, but it highly unusual that we would update columns `a` or `b` which are part of the UNIQUE KEY.

When the INSERT attempt fails due to the violation of a unique constraint, the ON DUPLICATE KEY part causes an UPDATE operation on the existing row.

Given that the PRIMARY KEY (or a UNIQUE KEY) of table2 is tuple `(a,b,c)`, we would typically only want to update columns other than a, b and c.

Something like this:

```
 INSERT INTO table2 (a, b, c, d)

 SELECT s.a
      , s.b 
      , s.c
      , s.d
   FROM table1 s
  WHERE s.id <> 0 

 ON DUPLICATE KEY 
 UPDATE d = VALUES(d)
```

That is a pattern that performs the operations we expect, as documented in the MySQL Reference Manual.

---

With the UNIQUE KEY as a set of three columns (a,b,c),  then the ON DUPLICATE KEY would not be executed based on the value of "one column".  That only gets fired when the attempt to do the INSERT fails with a unique key violation.

---

(The question falls way short of giving a specification, an actual description of what the "desired result" is. As the question is presented, we can't give any suggestion about how to achieve the desired result; we would just be guessing.)